# Colouring User Inputted Text depending on colour selection PHP

Tags: php, function

I've been asked to create a PHP page that will contain a form. This form should allow for a user to input a word and select a colour. Based on their selections the page should then echo out the user's word in the colour of their choosing. I began to try and implement it however ran into some problems. My code is below:

```
<?php
echo "
<html> 
<head> 
  <title>Colour Text</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
  <form name='colour_text' onsubmit='colour_text()' method='POST'>
    Word: <input type='text' name='word' /><br />
    Choose the colors: 
      <input type='radio' name='colour' value='bk' checked='checked' /> Black
      <input type='radio' name='colour' value='rd' /> Red
      <input type='radio' name='colour' value='be' /> Blue
      <input type='radio' name='colour' value='yw' /> Yellow
      <input type='submit' />
  </form>
</body>
</head>
</html>";

function colour_text($word, $colour)
{

$word = $_POST['word'];
$colour = $_POST['colour'];

    if ($colour == 'bk' ) 
    {
        echo '<div style=\"color:black;\">$word</div>';
    }
    if ($colour == 'rd' ) 
    {
        echo '<div style=\"color:red;\">$word</div>';
    }
    if ($colour == 'be' ) 
    {
        echo '<div style=\"color:blue;\">$word</div>';
    }
    if ($colour == 'yw' ) 
    {
        echo '<div style=\"color:yellow;\">$word</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Being new to PHP, I have searched and found some similar questions but nothing that is directly applicable to this.

Comment: When you say you 'ran into some problems', can you explain what you mean? But I think your main issue is understanding how functions are called in php; your onsubmit needs to provide a url to a file that will run your code on the server. it would look something like `onsubmit="color_text.php"`; and in your php file of that name you would have your if/echo stuff.

Comment: Sorry thanks for the answer, so would I be ok having a html file with the form on it and from there linking it to my php file (without the form present) using the on submit action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this, not so good code because of time, but it can be good  tutorial on your example, and will help you to learn PHP

Notice's on your code

1. **Use arrays or other similar data types**
2. **Always check if variable isset**
3. **Don't mix the HTML with PHP even in echo** even you can close ?> php tag and write html, but it isn't recommended as well
4. **You can attach ONLY JAVASCRIPT functions on DOM events**

   ```
   $colors = ['black', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow'];

   echo "
   <html> 
   <head> 
     <title>Colour Text</title> 
   </head> 
   <body> 
     <form name='colour_text' method='POST'>
       Word: <input type='text' name='word' /><br />
       Choose the colors: ";
   $checked = " checked='checked' ";
   foreach ($colors as $color) {
       echo "<input type='radio' name='colour' value='{$color}' {$checked}/> " . ucfirst($color) . " ";
       $checked = '';
   }

   echo "      <input type='submit' name='submitButton' />
     </form> ";

   if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])) {
       colour_text($_POST['word'], $_POST['colour']);
   }

   echo "
   </body>
   </head>
   </html>";

   function colour_text($word, $colour) {
       global $colors;
       $word = $_POST['word'];
       $colour = $_POST['colour'];

       if (!in_array($colour, $colors)) {
           $colour = 'black';
       }

       echo '<div style="color:' . $colour . ';">' . $word . '</div>';

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function colour_text() {
    // $_POST is global
    $word = $_POST['word'];

    switch ($_POST['colour']) {
        case 'bk': $colour = "black";
        case 'rd': $colour = "red";
        case 'be': $colour = "blue";
        case 'yw': $colour = "yellow";
        default: $colour = "black";
    }

    $result = "<div style=\"color:".$colour."\">".$word."</div>";

}

IF (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $result = colour_text();

    }ELSE{ // form not submitted
    // form ......
    $result = "<form action=\"".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."\" name=\"colour_text\" method=\"POST\">
    Word: <input type=\"text\" name=\"word\" value=\"\" /><br />
    Choose the colors: 
    <input type=\"radio\" name=\"colour\" value=\"bk\" checked=\"checked\" /> Black
    <input type=\"radio\" name=\"colour\" value=\"rd\" /> Red
    <input type=\"radio\" name=\"colour\" value=\"be\" /> Blue
    <input type=\"radio\" name=\"colour\" value=\"yw\" /> Yellow
    <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"\" />
</form>";
    }

echo("<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Colour Text</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
".$result."
</body>
</head>
</html>");
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i got a parse error when i tried this solution. The error was `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'colour_text' (T_STRING), expecting '(' in J:\UniServerZ1\www\7. PHP Functions\colouredtxt1.php on line 19`

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: result in J:\UniServer\www\colouredtxt1.php on line 40` thank again, getting this notice now. Any idea what this normally means?